# Is it possible to create a one to many association between a table and an Enum in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, enums, fastapi

In my FastAPI project I want to associate a table with multiple regions. The regions are stored in an Enum. Many-to-Many relationships in SQLAlchemy are generally possible, but I get an error message when adjusting the [documented behaviour](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html#setting-bi-directional-many-to-many) to an enum.

This is my code:

```
class RegionEnum(str, Enum):
    US = "us"
    EU = "eu"
    INDIA = "india"
    APAC = "apac"

association_table = Table(
    "association_table_check_region",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("left_id", ForeignKey("server.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("right_id", Enum(RegionEnum), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
)

class Server(Base):
    regions: Mapped[list[RegionEnum]] = relationship("RegionEnum", secondary=association_table)
```

When running my tests I get `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper[Check(check)], expression 'RegionEnum' failed to locate a name ('RegionEnum'). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'app.models.check.Check'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.`

I suppose SQLAlchemy is not aware of the enum, but how can I make it aware? Or in general: how do you set up a multiple select (1:M) of an enum in SQLAlchemy?

> I tried with a connection table before (basically a real table instead of the association table and it worked, I am looking for a proper solution.

Comment: Since there isn't a table on the other side, it isn't a many to many relationship on an SQL level. It's a 1:M relationship, where the column in the M-table is is limited to the enum (i.e. `ServerRegions: server_id, enum_value`). If you want it to be many to many, you'll have to create a table that represents the enum.

Comment: @MatsLindh That is absolutely correct, I worked with Django before, where 1:M equals M:M. Is there a simple way to do the 1:M without a separate table?

Comment: You can use an [Association Proxy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) to "hide" (conceal the usage of) the connection or association table and access the enum. Use a normal relation since `secondary` does not work.

Comment: @ivvija Thanks, this looks a lot like the M:M relation, I will try if this works with Enums.